# Is it possible to queue a function to a specific thread by its thread id using boost::asio?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I'm trying to queue a simple function on a specific thread by its thread id.

I don't need to stop the thread, just post a function to it. The function only needs to be executed by a specific time frame.

 I've been thinking of using `asio::post` to send the function, but not sure how to find and bind the thread. 

Is there a way I can do so? Or would it be more feasible to do it by saving the thread's native handler? (which I think I can do)

I'm new to multithreading and boost::asio, so any help would be great. 

 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to assign the task to a specific thread using the ID? You let asio do that for you.
 You can make the threads wait at a certain point by calling `asio::io_context::run` for example. Then as you will post the tasks, a random free thread will be picked from those waiting threads and it will execute the posted task. For example:

```
asio::io_context context;
asio::executor_work_guard guard(context.get_executor()); // used to manage the task status

auto workerThread = [&](){
     context.run(); // threads will block here, waiting for tasks to be posted and then execute them concurrently
};

auto foo = [](auto && value){
     // obtain mutex here
     std::cout << value << '\n';
     // release mutex 
};

auto threadA = std::thread(workerThread);
auto threadB = std::thread(workerThread);

// assign the tasks
context.post(std::bind(foo,1));
context.post(std::bind(foo,2));

guard.reset(); // inform the threads there is no more work to do
threadA.join();
threadB.join();
```

Comment: Oh the thing is the function needs to be posted to a specific thread, not any free working thread. If it's not possible on boost::asio, would a Linux kernel level approach be more realistic in this case?